# Margrittr pipe with matrix operations in R

Tags: r, matrix, pipe, magrittr

I'm working on some functions that take a matrix as input and provide a matrix as output. Is it possible to use the `magrittr` pipe with matrices without using the `.` placeholder? Ideally, I'd like these functions to be piped into each other like a `dplyr` chain. The issue is that I'm constantly forgetting to specify the `.` placeholder and getting errors.

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)  

# This works perfectly:
layout_align_x <- function(n = nodes, anchor, m = matrix){
  m[n, 1] <- m[anchor, 1]
  return(m)}

# This also works perfectly:
layout_align_x(c(1,2), 3, m)

# And this also: 
m %>% layout_align_x(c(1,2), 3, .)

# This returns error: 
m %>% layout_align_x(c(1,2), 3)
#Error in m[anchor, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

# The goal is:
m %>% 
  layout_align_x(c(1,2), 3) %>% 
  layout_align_x(c(3,4), 5)
```

Comment: You can either change your layout_align_x function so the matrix is the first input, or specify the inputs, as in (m= , n=c(1,2), ...)? (not tested) (the best solution is to not forget the ‘.’ :) )

Comment: Are you bound by the order of the input options?
If not, you can specify `layout_align_x <- function(m, anchor, n) { ...` and then `m %>% layout_align(c(1, 2), 3)` would work.

Comment: Hi both, I'm not bound by the order.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden, it does. I'll accept as soon as I'm able. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change  your function to

```
layout_align_x <- function(m = matrix, n = nodes, anchor){
  m[n, 1] <- m[anchor, 1]
  return(m)
}
```